# Read metadata from full Ajax websites

Tags: ajax, facebook

Since the Facebook bot doesn't support JavaScript, I need some method to make Facebook understand what `mydns.com/#!/awesome-page` means.

I'm thinking about an Apache [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) method if the user-agent is from Facebook, but what is this user-agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... if the user-agent is from Facebook, but what is this user-agent?

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/:

> The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

Comment: "cannot" != can't... sorry, I'm not english mother lenguaje.
Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

I made a PHP-only page with the metadata for Facebook and a script in Java to redirect the browser to the original page.